# Disable clickable element only within the div area

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have a thumbnail image that has an overlay element on it (slides up). when you click the background image It should open a lightbox (which is does). when you click the overlay div, it will open a seperate modal. **The issue is: when I click the overlay div, both the lightbox and modal open.** I think this is difficult to explain but I'd like to know how to disable clicking through the orange div box

**Using an a blank href will not work in this instance. When I do this, the lightbox duplicates images.**

```css
        .overlay {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          background: rgba(47, 74, 102, .6);
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 100%;
          height: 0;
          transition: .5s ease;
          cursor: pointer;
          display: block;
        }

        .overlay {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 100%;
          height: 0;
          transition: .5s ease;
          cursor: pointer;
          display: block;
        }

        .imagetext:hover .overlay {
          height: 100%;
        }

        .mySlides {display:none;}

        .overlaytitle {
          margin-top: 1rem;
            color: white;
          opacity: 1.0;
            font-size: 1rem;
            position: absolute;
          font-family: oswald;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 1rem;
        }


        .overlaysubtitle {
            color: white;
          font-family: lato;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-style: italic;
        }

        .fullproj{
          background-color: #f17e5a;
            bottom: 0;
          align-content: center;
            height: 30%;
            line-height: 30%;
          padding-top: 7%;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: oswald;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 14px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }


        .modalbutton{
            width: 100%;
            height: 30%;
            background-color: #f17e5a;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1rem;
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border:none;
            font-family: oswald;
            font-weight: thin;
            cursor: pointer;

        }


        .modalbutton:hover{
            background-color:#bb5c5a;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="responsive brands">
          <div class="gallery">
             <div class="imagetext"> 
              <a href="mpimg/viva/box.png" alt="Viva Lifestyle Box and Bar" rel="lightbox1" data-lightbox="example-set"  title="Viva Lifestyle Box and Bar">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlaytitle">Viva Lifestyle<br>
                    <div class="overlaysubtitle">Branding</div><br>
                  </div> 
                            <button class="modalbutton"><a href="#">VIEW FULL PROJECT</a></button>
                        </div>   
                <img src="Img/portfolio/Branding/viva.png" alt="EXAMPLE IMG" width="600" height="400" class="image"> 
              </a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Any JavaScript/jQuery involved? The CSS and HTML doesn't look like it can support the functionality you have described.

Comment: Yes but it's pretty deep in my code because I have a lightbox. Basically I'm wondering if theres a way to disable clicking behind that orange div when the overlay pops up. it wants to click the lightbox and modal at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, whatever I tell you is a shot in the dark, so here's a shot in the dark: read up on [Event Propagation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by css

```
.modalbutton {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```